# HTML Duplicate pages based on variables

Tags: html

Apologies for the 'cryptic' title, I'm honestly not sure how to word it.

I'm wanting to make a website, sort of like an "application download" site. I'm wanting to have separate pages per item available for download containing basic info like the name, download button, size ect. The current way I designed is just the same code copy pasted over and over in separate files with only the tag contents changed. Is it possible to create one single file of sorts that controls the entire thing, so I'd only have to design one main page, instead of multiple?

For example, my current setup would be:

```
---------------------
app1.html
---------------------
<h1>App #1</h1>
<button>Download (7MB)</button>



---------------------
app2.html
---------------------
<h1>App #2</h1>
<button>Download (23MB)</button>
```

But I'm wondering if it's possible to have something like this:

```
---------------------
design.(extension)
---------------------
<h1>[appname]</h1>
<button>Download ([size])</button>



---------------------
app1.html
---------------------
appname = "App #1"
size = "7MB"
// Automatically load the website design from a separate central file, and use the 'app1' variables
```

I believe pages work for this, but I'm unaware if they can have variables of sorts

Comment: You may want to read up on SPA (Single Page Applications).

Comment: This is called Templating. There are a lot of templating engines available, but you have not included any stack information. I would include a common one if you had.